# elasticsearch IndexShardMissingException

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I receive this error whenever I start my node.
What's going wrong?

```
[2012-10-12 10:00:38,196][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.status] [Gorgilla] [monitoring][1], node[dbnnA1NOQ1ubysyADvazFg], [P], s[INITIALIZING]: 

Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.status.IndicesStatusRequest@968f9] org.elasticsearch.index.**IndexShardMissingException**:
[monitoring][1] 

missing at org.elasticsearch.index.service.InternalIndexService.shardSafe(InternalIndexService.java:175) at

org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.status.TransportIndicesStatusAction.shardOperation(TransportIndicesStatusAction.java:153) at 

org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.status.TransportIndicesStatusAction.shardOperation(TransportIndicesStatusAction.java:59) at 

org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction.performOperation

(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:234) at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction

$AsyncBroadcastAction.performOperation(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:211) at 

org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction$1.run(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:187) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run

(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

my ES version -> 0.19.0

settings:

```
ES_HOME/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf file:
 set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE=1024
 set.default.ES_MIN_MEM=1048576
 set.default.ES_MAX_MEM=1048576

elasticsearch.yml
 index.cache.field.type: soft
 index.cache.field.max_size: 1000
 bootstrap.mlockall: true

index settings:
"number_of_shards":5
"number_of_replicas":1
```

Comment: Any help on this?